# Strange artifacts in a simple object

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, artifacts

I'm modeling a mirror. I created this frame by extruding planes for the outside part and then connecting both holes from the front and the back. I used and applied a mirror modifier for the Y axis.

Everything looks good until I render the file, it shows a strange line as you can see below in the screenshot. I can solve this by using a Subdivision modifier but then I lose the sharp edges. Tried adding more edge loops and beveling but it seems I'm missing something.

Is there anything I can do to avoid these artifacts when rendering?

[image: Top left image shows a weird sewing artifact when rendering.]

[image]

Comment: have you tried recalculating normals in edit mode?
You can also select the edges and increase their Crease value in the Edge data on the N-Panel so they stay sharp when you add a subdivision modifier.

Comment: I tried recalculating normals too but didn't help. The other answer I got worked but I will try increasing the Crease value too and learn from this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have activated the *Smooth Shading* option of the T menu, but your object is a low-poly mesh. If you try to smooth a low-poly mesh these strange artifacts can happen. It's true that you have given your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier that is used to simulate a high-poly mesh, but you have disabled its *Display modifier in Viewport*, so the artifacts still appear.

You say that you did that because you wanted to have both smooth and sharp edges.

If you want to have a smooth appearance but at the same time keep some sharp edges, add some additional edge loops close to the angles you want to keep sharp. Here is how:

[image]

Comment: If I enable it it will make the object look smoother, but I'd like to keep its edges sharp. Thus I activated Smooth Shading to have a mor rounded shape without adding more edge loops. Is there a way to keep Smooth Shading activated and avoid the artifacts?

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! That's exactly what I wanted.